# How split a string into an array which i want to push inside an other array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, split

If i have this array:

```
 array = ["1\r\ndate\r\ntext\"...", "2\r\ndate\r\ntext", "3\r\ndate\r\ntext_one\r\ntext_two."]
```

And I want to split in:

```
array = [[1, date, "text"],[2, date, "text"], [3, date, "text", "text"]]
```

You know...dividing that strings into array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map over the array and split the substrings

```
result = array.map { |input| input.split }
```

As @davenewton mentions this can be simplified to the following

```
array.map(&:split)
```

If the delimiters of the substring change then you can pass the new delimeter as an argument to `split` for example if you used `:`

```
result = array.map { |input| input.split(':') }
```